# How is a GDB xmethod enabled?

Tags: python, gdb, clion, xmethod

When creating an 'xmethod' how do I activate it in GDB?

```
source /home/me/xmethod/my-class.py
enable xmethod
```

[The documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Writing-an-Xmethod.html) does not provide an activation example.

```
help enable xmethod
GDB command to enable a specified (group of) xmethod(s).

 Usage: enable xmethod [LOCUS-REGEXP [NAME-REGEXP]]

 LOCUS-REGEXP is a regular expression matching the location of the
 xmethod matchers.  If it is omitted, all registered xmethods matchers
 from all loci are enabled.  A locus could be 'global', a regular expression
 matching the current program spaces filename, or a regular expression
 matching filenames of objfiles.  Locus could be 'progspace' to specify that
 only xmethods from the current progspace should be enabled.

 NAME-REGEXP is a regular expression matching the names of xmethods
 within a given locus.  If this omitted for a specified locus, then all
 registered xmethod matchers in the locus are enabled.  To enable only
 a certain xmethods managed by a single matcher, the name regexp can be
 specified as matcher-name-regexp;xmethod-name-regexp.
```

The method does not seem to be active.

```
info xmethod
```

Returns a list of nothing.

Note: I am running GDB under CLion.

What I am wanting is a good and proper example.

The [source code for xmethod.py](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=gdb/python/lib/gdb/command/xmethods.py) does provide some documentation but not an example.

**Any advice on the proper way to specify the locus and name?**

- [GDB source for managing xmethods](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=gdb/python/py-xmethods.c;h=1467e52a96067641466e7d85e16a70924e89cc7d;hb=HEAD)
- [Canonical Docs on xmethod](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Writing-an-Xmethod.html)
- [Source Code for xmethods.py](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=gdb/python/lib/gdb/command/xmethods.py)
- [Source Code for xmethod.py a sample](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=gdb/python/lib/gdb/xmethod.py)
- [A discussion about xmethods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73025746/what-does-python-do-inside-the-gdb-debugger/73043511)
- [The libstdc++ xmethod](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/python/libstdcxx/v6/xmethods.py)

Here is [the `my-class.py`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Writing-an-Xmethod.html) I am trying to load:

```py
import gdb
import gdb.xmethod

# https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Xmethods-In-Python.html#Xmethods-In-Python

class MyClass_geta(gdb.xmethod.XMethod):
    def __init__(self):
        gdb.xmethod.XMethod.__init__(self, 'geta')

    def get_worker(self, method_name):
        if method_name == 'geta':
            return MyClassWorker_geta()


class MyClass_sum(gdb.xmethod.XMethod):
    def __init__(self):
        gdb.xmethod.XMethod.__init__(self, 'sum')

    def get_worker(self, method_name):
        if method_name == 'operator+':
            return MyClassWorker_plus()


class MyClassMatcher(gdb.xmethod.XMethodMatcher):
    def __init__(self):
        gdb.xmethod.XMethodMatcher.__init__(self, 'MyClassMatcher')
        # List of methods 'managed' by this matcher
        self.methods = [MyClass_geta(), MyClass_sum()]

    def match(self, class_type, method_name):
        if class_type.tag != 'MyClass':
            return None
        workers = []
        for method in self.methods:
            if method.enabled:
                worker = method.get_worker(method_name)
                if worker:
                    workers.append(worker)

        return workers

class MyClassWorker_geta(gdb.xmethod.XMethodWorker):
    def get_arg_types(self):
        return None

    def get_result_type(self, obj):
        return gdb.lookup_type('int')

    def __call__(self, obj):
        return obj['a_']


class MyClassWorker_plus(gdb.xmethod.XMethodWorker):
    def get_arg_types(self):
        return gdb.lookup_type('MyClass')

    def get_result_type(self, obj):
        return gdb.lookup_type('int')

    def __call__(self, obj, other):
        return obj['a_'] + other['a_']
```

Comment: xmethods are usually by default enabled. What does `info xmethod` tell you about your xmethod?

Comment: @ssbssa I updated the post with the output from `info xmethod` which is empty.

Comment: Is the LOCUS-REGEXP the path to the python script? the directory containing the script? something else?

Comment: You have your xmethod in some python file, right? Then have you loaded it in gdb, e.g. with `source /path/to/your/xmethod.py`.

Comment: Yes, I have it in a python file /home/me/xmethods/my-class.py. I have loaded it in gdb with `source  /home/me/xmethods/my-class.py`.  I updated the question with the source for `my-class.py`. Note that `import gdb` does not include `gdb.xmethod` it needed to be included in its own import.

Comment: You're missing the `gdb.xmethod.register_xmethod_matcher(None, MyClassMatcher())` call to register the xmethod in gdb.

Comment: @ssbssa if you add this as an answer I will accept it as a solution.