# Set up GDB C++ STL xmethods

Tags: python, gdb, xmethod

I'm trying to enable `xmethods` as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40637353). However, `info xmethod` returns nothing even if I called `enable xmethod` beforehand:

```
(gdb) enable xmethod
(gdb) info xmethod
(gdb)
```

How can I import the xmethods into my GDB?

Note that this is not a duplicate of [How is a GDB xmethod enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73155658), since that question is about enabling **custom** xmethod definitions instead of built-in STL definitions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `register_libstdcxx_xmethods` manually as mentioned in [this thread](https://www.spinics.net/lists/gcchelp/msg53689.html). The set up is similar to [pretty-printers](https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport).

More specifically, clone gcc to your home directory, and modify `~/.gdbinit`: (assume your username is `j3soon`)

```
python
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/j3soon/gcc/libstdc++-v3/python')
# from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
# register_libstdcxx_printers(None)
from libstdcxx.v6.xmethods import register_libstdcxx_xmethods
register_libstdcxx_xmethods(None)
end
```

You may also uncomment the 2 lines above to enable pretty printers. Then, relaunch gdb:

```
(gdb) info xmethod
Xmethods in global:
  libstdc++::shared_ptr
    get
    operator->
    operator*
    operator[]
    use_count
    unique
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--
```

Note: Don't use `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` when compiling. The xmethods seem to fail if the libcxx debug flag is used.