# How to view the value corresponding to a specific key in std::unordered_map in gdb?

Tags: c++, gdb

I know that printing the unordered_map variable can output all elements, but currently I have a scenario where the unordered_map contains millions of elements and I only care about the value corresponding to a specific key. How can I print it in gdb? I tried using `operator[]` and `at` but neither works.[image]

In addition, I have already included `-g`, `-O0`, and `-fno-inline` when compiling.

Comment: Could you share your compilation flags? Try compiling the program with `-O0` and `-ggdb3` if you haven't done so already.

Comment: Do you have [xmethods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73673643/1983398) enabled?